# Remember scroll position in lazycolumn?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am aware of the remember lazy list state and it works fine

```
 setContent {       
       Test(myList) // Call Test with a dummy list
    }

  @Composable
    fun Test(data: List<Int>){
        val state = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(state = state) {
            items(data){ item ->Text("$item")}
          }
     }
```

It will remember scroll position and after every rotation and change configuration it will be the same
But whenever I try to catch data from database and use some method like collectAsState
it doesn't work and it seem an issue

```
   setContent{
      val myList by viewModel.getList.collectAsState(initial = listOf())
      Test(myList)
   }
```

Comment: use key on LazyColumn  items so its now Recomposite if the data  same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Save LazyListState Forever

```
/**
 * Static field, contains all scroll values
 */
private val SaveMap = mutableMapOf<String, KeyParams>()

private data class KeyParams(
    val params: String = "",
    val index: Int,
    val scrollOffset: Int
)

/**
 * Save scroll state on all time.
 * @param key value for comparing screen
 * @param params arguments for find different between equals screen
 * @param initialFirstVisibleItemIndex see [LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex]
 * @param initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset see [LazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset]
 */
@Composable
fun rememberForeverLazyListState(
    key: String,
    params: String = "",
    initialFirstVisibleItemIndex: Int = 0,
    initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset: Int = 0
): LazyListState {
    val scrollState = rememberSaveable(saver = LazyListState.Saver) {
        var savedValue = SaveMap[key]
        if (savedValue?.params != params) savedValue = null
        val savedIndex = savedValue?.index ?: initialFirstVisibleItemIndex
        val savedOffset = savedValue?.scrollOffset ?: initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        LazyListState(
            savedIndex,
            savedOffset
        )
    }
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            val lastIndex = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
            val lastOffset = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            SaveMap[key] = KeyParams(params, lastIndex, lastOffset)
        }
    }
    return scrollState
}
```

Usage:

```
LazyColumn(
    state = rememberForeverLazyListState(key = "Overview")
)
```

[Click here to check the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123229/9181558).

## Save ScrollState Forever

Taking inspiration from the previous answer I created a similar `remember` method to save the `ScrollState`.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable

/**
 * Static field, contains all scroll values
 */
private val SaveMap = mutableMapOf<String, ScrollKeyParams>()

private data class ScrollKeyParams(
  val value: Int
)

/**
 * Save scroll state on all time.
 * @param key value for comparing screen
 * @param initial see [ScrollState.value]
 */
@Composable
fun rememberForeverScrollState(
  key: String,
  initial: Int = 0
): ScrollState {
  val scrollState = rememberSaveable(saver = ScrollState.Saver) {
    val scrollValue: Int = SaveMap[key]?.value ?: initial
    SaveMap[key] = ScrollKeyParams(scrollValue)
    return@rememberSaveable ScrollState(scrollValue)
  }
  DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    onDispose {
      SaveMap[key] = ScrollKeyParams(scrollState.value)
    }
  }
  return scrollState
}
```

For usage:

```
val scrollState = rememberForeverScrollState("history_screen")
  
Column(
  modifier = modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
 ...
}
```

## Old Answer

Unfortunately for now there's not a native way to do so, but you can use this code:

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
```

`listState` has 3 methods:

- `firstVisibleItemIndex`
- `firstVisibleItemScrollOffset`
- `isScrollInProgress`

All of them are `State()` so you will always get the data as it updates. For example, if you start scrolling the list, `isScrollInProgress` will change from `false` to `true`.

**SAVE AND RESTORE STATE**

```
val listState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(viewModel.index, viewModel.offset)

  LaunchedEffect(key1 = listState.isScrollInProgress) {
    if (!listState.isScrollInProgress) {
      viewModel.index = listState.firstVisibleItemIndex
      viewModel.offset = listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
    }
  }
```

Comment: Old answer actually resolves my issue.

I recompose all the view every 10 seconds (because of live data polling). And my LazyRow was not keeping its scrollstate between recomposition. With the new solution, it was resetting the firstVisibleItemIndex and offset to 0. Then on second recomposition, state was reset to the real previous scroll.

So thank you to have kept the old one.