# Remember LazyColumn Scroll Position - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to save/remember LazyColumn scroll position when I navigate away from one composable screen to another. Even if I pass a rememberLazyListState to a LazyColumn the scroll position is not saved after I get back to my first composable screen. Can someone help me out?

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun DisplayTasks(
    tasks: List<Task>,
    navigateToTaskScreen: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = tasks,
            key = { _, task ->
                task.id
            }
        ) { _, task ->
            LazyColumnItem(
                toDoTask = task,
                navigateToTaskScreen = navigateToTaskScreen
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Stefan, Did you find the solution? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well if you literally want to save it, you must store it is something like a viewmodel where it remains preserved. The `remember`ed stuff only lasts till the Composable gets destroyed. If you navigate to another screen, the previous Composables are destroyed and along with them, the scroll state

Comment: Is there a way to use rememberSaveable with this lazyListState?

Comment: `rememberSaveable` works the same as `rememer`, the only difference being that it preserves state across configuration changes. The device rotation, for the layman.

Comment: but in view system it is enough to set `@+id` for `recyclerview` or `nestedscrollview` and it remembers the scroll state after returning to the fragment, you don't need to use any keys/variables with `viewmodel`, so basically compose removes this easy way and gives nothing in return, only custom solutions...

Comment: and why do you say "literally save it" like it something unusual? you can have a long list of some items and when you click on some to check details (details screen) then after returning from details screen a user expects to be at last position where he stopped

Comment: also even this solution doesn't work, with items from viewmodel (flow from room database), still returns to the first item

Comment: @user924 you okay sir?

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper yes, so what about View System, why do you say "literally" when it's normal to save it after changing screens or  you never used it at View System? Also I found the issue why this solution didn't work with Compose, because I didn't have fixed size for Image for items, so the height could be changed dynamically, it wasn't the issue for View System and RecyclerView, still not ideal solution

Comment: the problem is in PagingData with Compose -https://stackoverflow.com/q/76100415/7767664. So `LazyColumn` doesn't require any custom manipulation to save scroll, it does it by itself, the problem is that data can be zero initially on config changes or when you return back to the screen. So from all answers the only one is correct here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/75084854/7767664 and should be accepted instead of this one

Comment: The link is dead, sir.

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
 * Static field, contains all scroll values
 */
private val SaveMap = mutableMapOf<String, KeyParams>()

private data class KeyParams(
    val params: String = "",
    val index: Int,
    val scrollOffset: Int
)

/**
 * Save scroll state on all time.
 * @param key value for comparing screen
 * @param params arguments for find different between equals screen
 * @param initialFirstVisibleItemIndex see [LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex]
 * @param initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset see [LazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset]
 */
@Composable
fun rememberForeverLazyListState(
    key: String,
    params: String = "",
    initialFirstVisibleItemIndex: Int = 0,
    initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset: Int = 0
): LazyListState {
    val scrollState = rememberSaveable(saver = LazyListState.Saver) {
        var savedValue = SaveMap[key]
        if (savedValue?.params != params) savedValue = null
        val savedIndex = savedValue?.index ?: initialFirstVisibleItemIndex
        val savedOffset = savedValue?.scrollOffset ?: initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        LazyListState(
            savedIndex,
            savedOffset
        )
    }
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            val lastIndex = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
            val lastOffset = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            SaveMap[key] = KeyParams(params, lastIndex, lastOffset)
        }
    }
    return scrollState
}
```

example of use

```
LazyColumn(
    state = rememberForeverLazyListState(key = "Overview")
)
```

Comment: is there are a similar solution for ScrollState? Because each page will have both LazyListState as well as ScrollState.

Comment: I don't really understand what `params` is for, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @ubuntudroid
If the screen depends on the content. You can have a user profile screen and without `params` (for example: userId) the scroll state will be the same for each of the users

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But couldn't this also be handled via the key? Something like `key = "profile_${user_id}"`.

Comment: Yes, you can. But this is not the latest version. I have places where there are several horizontal scrolls on the same screen. I tied this to navigation where the key is the title of the screen to reset all states by key when there is no screen in the backStack. @ubuntudroid

Comment: Hm, I don't think I understand, but it works well enough for me without the parameters, so thanks anyway for your reply!

Comment: What is `rememberForeverLazyListState`?

Comment: It does not work for first screen (tab) on an HorizontalPager. I used it on an HorizontalPager with two composable screens. The second tab really keeps the scroll position but not the first one. Probably i miss something because the pager is on a bottom navigation view. Changing bottom tabs and returning to the one with the HorizontalPager, then the first tab remembers correct the scroll position

Answer (score 4):

```
@Composable
fun persistedLazyScrollState(viewModel: YourViewModel): LazyListState {
        val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(viewModel.firstVisibleItemIdx, viewModel.firstVisibleItemOffset)
        DisposableEffect(key1 = null) {
            onDispose {
                viewModel.firstVisibleItemIdx = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
                viewModel.firstVisibleItemOffset = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }
        }
        return scrollState
    }
}
```

Above I defined a helper function to persist scroll state when a composable is disposed of. All that is needed is a ViewModel with variables for firstVisibleItemIdx and firstVisibleItemOffet.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
   .fillMaxSize()
   .verticalScroll(
       persistedScrollState(viewModel = viewModel)
   ) {
   //Your content here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `LazyColumn` should save scroll position out of the box when navigating to next screen. If it doesn't work, this may be a bug described here ([issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179397301)). Basically check if the list becomes empty when changing screens, e.g. because you observe a cold Flow or LiveData (so the initial value is used).

Comment: Not necessarily true if you refresh the data when the user returns.

Comment: it may happen with `PagingData`, the data from cache is being returned with a delay, so initially it sets empty list and only later it will return your data (and there is no any REST request, it's 100% from cache)

Comment: Do you know how to fix it then? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76100415/7767664

Answer (score 2):

Faced with same problem, I've tried to save LazyScrollState in viewModell and it looks like it works als desired. Need more tests but worth posting here, because it's very simple:

in your ViewModel:

```
var llState: LazyListState by mutableStateOf( LazyListState(0,0))
```

and in Composable:

```
LazyColumn(
            state = myViewModel.llState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentPadding = it,
            userScrollEnabled = true
        ) {
          //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Composable
fun persistedScrollState(viewModel: ParentViewModel): ScrollState {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState(viewModel.scrollPosition)
    DisposableEffect(key1 = null) {
        onDispose {
            viewModel.scrollPosition = scrollState.value
        }
    }
    return scrollState
}
```

Above I defined a helper function to persist scroll state when a composable is disposed of. All that is needed is a ViewModel with a scroll position variable.

Hope this helps someone!

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
   .fillMaxSize()
   .verticalScroll(
       persistedScrollState(viewModel = viewModel)
   ) {
   //Your content here
}
```

Comment: OP was asking for a solution for `LazyColumn`. Your solution unfortunately works with `ScrollState` and not with `LazyListState` which is required for `LazyColumn`.

Comment: Good point, solutions are similar so I'll post another!

Answer (score 0):

### Save ScrollState

I took @Константин Казаченко answer and I changed it a little bit to support ScrollState using `rememberForeverScrollState`.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable

/**
 * Static field, contains all scroll values
 */
private val SaveMap = mutableMapOf<String, ScrollKeyParams>()

private data class ScrollKeyParams(
  val value: Int
)

/**
 * Save scroll state on all time.
 * @param key value for comparing screen
 * @param initial see [ScrollState.value]
 */
@Composable
fun rememberForeverScrollState(
  key: String,
  initial: Int = 0
): ScrollState {
  val scrollState = rememberSaveable(saver = ScrollState.Saver) {
    val scrollValue: Int = SaveMap[key]?.value ?: initial
    SaveMap[key] = ScrollKeyParams(scrollValue)
    return@rememberSaveable ScrollState(scrollValue)
  }
  DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    onDispose {
      SaveMap[key] = ScrollKeyParams(scrollState.value)
    }
  }
  return scrollState
}
```

For usage:

```
val scrollState = rememberForeverScrollState("history_screen")
  
Column(
  modifier = modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
 ...
}
```