# How to manage scroll states with Jetpcak compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, fragment-backstack

Single activity has three screens,

```
S1(User List) -> LazyColumn

S2(FormA) -> Column(Scrollable)

S3(FormB) -> Column(Scrollable)
```

---

Below are four possible scenarios of visiting screens with vertical position of scroll sate mentioned in the round bracket,

**Fresh Start:**

```
S1(top) -> S2(top)[scroll to bottom & click Next] -> S3(top)
```

**Back:**

```
S1(top) -> S2(top)[scroll to bottom & click Next] -> S3(top)[back] 
-> S2(bottom)[back] -> S1(top)
```

**Partial-Back:**

```
S1(top) -> S2(top)[scroll to bottom & click Next] -> S3(top)[back]  
-> S2(bottom) -> S3(top)
```

**Restart:**

```
S1(top) -> S2(top)[scroll to bottom & click Next] -> S3(top)[back] 
-> S2(bottom)[back] -> S1(top) -> S2(top)[scroll to bottom & click Next] -> S3(top)
```

---

What I am trying to achieve over here is simple Fragment's back-stack functionality.

There are three approaches for this problem which in future can be applicable to all the screens,

1. Store all LazyListState & ScrollState states in [ViewMdoel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68611826)
2. However, we should not keep view related fields in VIewModel so better solution would be to [hoist](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) all LazyListState & ScrollState states into UserRoute.
3. Maintain all LazyListState states [globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123229), potential pitfall is giving unique key param for all main and nested LazyRow & LazyColumn Composables throughout project.

**Issue:** All three solutions have same drawback, when restarting the same screen(recomposing for a new user) last scroll states are maintained.

**Q1)** When moving forward screen should recompose as a new screen, but on back press screen should recompose at exact old state including scroll states, how to achieve this?

**Q2)** Is there an easy approach where jetpack compose system handles scroll state by default as a part of back-stack functionality? Because, there are screens which has more than five nested vertical & horizontal scrolls, and managing all of those manually could be error prone.

Sample code [Repo](https://github.com/chitrang200889/Scrollstate), Reference [Video](https://youtu.be/XXDPtZ955wo)

Comment: Compose Navigation will to it for you out of the box

Comment: I guess that is up to the point of Route, all screens after route are manually handled. Please follow this Jetnews app sample code https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/home/HomeRoute.kt

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point right, if the view(or in this case `rememerLazyViewState`) is in view tree at the moment of being put into the back stack, it's gonna be saved.