# Resume the previous scroll location of a LazyVerticalGrid after navigate to other screen and come back in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, grid, android-jetpack-compose

Assume that I have a home screen where I have many clickable Cards, and I use a LazyVerticalList to display and scroll through these Cards. After clicked on one of the Card and navigate to other screen and then return back to home screen, it reset the scroll location to the very top (beginning).

Below are my implementation using the rememberLazyGridState

```
HomeScreen.kt

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    onThemeUpdated: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val scrollState:LazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()
    viewModel.saveScrollState(scrollState)

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopBar(darkTheme, onThemeUpdated) }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(state = scrollState, columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
                items(featureList) { (imageId, titleId, routeId) ->
                    AppScreenCard(
                        imageId = imageId,
                        titleId = titleId,
                        navController = navController,
                        routeId = routeId
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
HomeViewModel.kt

class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _scrollState = mutableStateOf<LazyGridState?>(null)
    val scrollState: State<LazyGridState?> = _scrollState

    fun saveScrollState(scrollState: LazyGridState) {
        _scrollState.value = scrollState
    }
}
```

Apparently, it doesn't work?

I think it just reset everything.

*Edit

my featureList and AppScreenCard are like this:

```
val featureList = listOf(
    Triple(R.drawable._business_card, AllQuizScreenDestination.titleRes, AllQuizScreenDestination.routeRes),
    Triple(R.drawable._business_card, BusinessCardScreenDestination.titleRes, BusinessCardScreenDestination.routeRes),
    Triple(R.drawable._business_card, RandomQuizScreenDestination.titleRes, RandomQuizScreenDestination.routeRes)
)


@Composable
fun AppScreenCard(
    @DrawableRes imageId: Int,
    @StringRes titleId: Int,
    navController: NavHostController,
    @StringRes routeId: Int
) {
    val route = stringResource(id = routeId)
    ElevatedCard(
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 6.dp
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable { navController.navigate(route = route) }
        ,

....

}
```

Comment: You need to saveState in ```NavController``` so that when you come back to screen it will preserve the state.

Comment: excuse me but how can i save the state of the navcontroller?

Comment: You don't need to manually save scroll state at all - that is done for you without any of the ViewModel code you have. You code has a `items(featureList)`, but you don't say where `featureList` came from or how you are populating it. Please include that code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake The post was edited and now includes the requested code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** 
As suggested by a comment and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75084854/8331157) in a related question, the `LazyVerticalGrid` should store the scroll position by itself. That it doesn't work in your case even though your `featureList` is constant seems like it could be a bug.

---

As a workaround, you can store the scroll position in your ViewModel as follows:

First, add two new properties to your ViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel () : ViewModel() {

    // store the current scroll states
    var scrollIndex: Int by mutableStateOf(0)
    var scrollOffset: Int by mutableStateOf(0)
}
```

Then you could access these two fields as follows:

```
@Composable
HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val scrollState: LazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState(
        viewModel.scrollIndex, 
        viewModel.scrollOffset
    )

    // after each scroll, update values in ViewModel
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
        if (!scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
            viewModel.scrollIndex = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
            viewModel.scrollOffset = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that you are not creating a new Composable with a new ViewModel instance, but that is a topic for another question.

Comment: Excuse me but what is the listState?

Comment: @vinhDev3006 I am sorry, it was meant to be `scrollState` instead of `listState`. I edited my post and corrected it. If this answer resolves your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: i don't really think it works but thanks btw

Comment: So did you try it? If it doesn't work, check your navigation implementation. Make sure you are calling something like `navController.popBackStack()` instead of manually navigating to the same route again, which will recreate the Composable and the ViewModel.