Jetpack Compose LazyList scroll position not maintained after navigation
I am using Jetpack Compose in my app and have encountered an issue where the scroll position in a LazyColumn is not maintained when navigating away from the screen and then returning. I am using rememberLazyListState to manage the scroll state, but it always resets when I come back to the progressingWorkoutScreen.
I have tried using rememberSaveable for the list state but the issue persists. What could be causing this, and how can I ensure the scroll position is maintained when navigating back to this screen?
Any help would be appreciated!
val listState = rememberLazyListState()

LazyColumn(
    state = listState,
    userScrollEnabled = scrollEnabled,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    items(notes) { note ->
        swipeBox(
            onDelete = { /* delete logic */ },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            noteCell(
                note = note,
                onPinClicked = { /* pin logic */ },
                onTextChanged = { /* text change logic */ }
            )
        }
    }

    itemsIndexed(progressingSectionExercises) { section, sectionExercise ->
        progressingWorkoutSection(
            section,
            navController,
            exerciseViewModel,
            progressingWorkoutViewModel,
            sectionExercise
        )
    }
}


Welcome! Please edit your post and also include where notes and progressSectionExercise are coming from.

Here is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611320/remember-lazycolumn-scroll-position-jetpack-compose
